# change the default format for my "Modified" site column

Tags: javascript, css, page-layout, html

I am working on an enterprisewiki site collection, and I want to change the date format for the following message at the top of each wiki page:- 
[image]

I want to change the date format to be somrthing such as `15 Sep 2014` instead of the defualt `9/15/2014` .

Inside the default page layout I got the following code to display the message:-

```
<div class="ms-descriptiontext ewiki-margin">
                     <SharePoint:FormattedString FormatText="<%$Resources:wss,wikidiff_lastmodifiedby%>" runat="server">
                        <SharePoint:FormField id="modifiedFieldCtrl" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Modified" runat="server"/>
                        <SharePoint:UserField id="editorFieldCtrl" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Editor" runat="server"/>
                     </SharePoint:FormattedString>
                     <PublishingWebControls:EditPageHyperLink id="editPageLink" Text="<%$Resources:cms,enterwiki_editpage%>" runat="server"/>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the locale for a specific site, go to the Site Settings area and select Regional Settings from the Site Administration group of links.

For more options you can check:

http://blog.funknstyle.com/2012/08/working-with-date-formats-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: but this approach will not allow me to get the following custom format "15 Sep 2014", is this right ? ?? Also i am using SP 2013 , where your link is referring to 2010, does this make any differences ?

Comment: Otherwise you can use the custom columna s described in link. And change the field name to your custom fieldname.

Comment: You can try both the approaches.

Comment: but let say i created a new calculated columns ,what will be the formula  i should use?

Comment: You can check the link its defined there.